# Pack arbitrary number of bits

Tags: c++, encryption, pack

What would be a good way of packing an arbitrary number of bits? I have sentences which are known to only contain certain characters and want to encrypt. Hence an option is to use fewer bits to represent these characters and encrypt the characters in the process.

I looked at std::bitset, but it requires me to specify the size of the bitset as a constant, which will not do.

I would also like to know how the packed bits can then be converted back to characters to obscure the output.

ie if I pack A to 1000 and B to 0100, the resultant 8 bits of packing is 1000 0100 which is another character.

Btw, this is not supposed to be a strong form of encryption at all

Comment: It isn't *any* form of encryption...

Comment: Look up how Base64 works. That's "packing" every six bits into eight bits (so 3 input bytes become four output bytes). You can use a similar logic.

Comment: @KerrekSB its more of an exercise than anything else

Comment: Sounds like lossless compression. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression

Comment: @KerrekSB and this is done after other procedures. Its not the only thing. I am more concerned about how to implement this in C++

Comment: Done _after_ other procedures? Good encryption does use compression as one of the steps, but importantly does so as one of the first steps. It's hard to explain exactly why in this comment, but intuitively after compression there's less data available to crack the key with.

Comment: @MSalters before or after, depending on the mode.

Comment: @user929404: Obviously you decompress after decryption. That's the only "mode" where it should happen afterwards. I'm getting the strong impression that C++ is not your real problem here.

Comment: @MSalters If things sound weird, its because I did not come up with the scheme, but have to implement it

Comment: @user929404: Send the job back. Seriously, someone who thinks up a scheme that has `1000 0100` as both a single-character encoding and the encoding of `AB` should be flipping burgers, not handing out assignments.

Comment: @MSalters That was an example, but it is along those lines and quite dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [`dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html). It is like `std::bitset` but it can change its size dynamically.

Also, you can use [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) which will do what you need as a side effect of slightly unfortunate historical decision to implement it as a bitset.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're literally only encoding an alphabet of sixteen letters (say A-P), then you can build a lookup table:

```
unsigned char table[256] = {};
table['A'] = 0x0;
table['B'] = 0x1;
// ...
table['P'] = 0xF;
```

Now you can encode every two letters `x` and `y` as:

```
table[x] * 0x10 + table[y]
```

You should probably combine this with a unique-padding scheme to pad your input data up to an even number of letters (some variant of PKCS padding should work).

Answer (score 0):

"I would also like to know how the packed bits can then be converted back to characters"
This is basic coding theory. You probably want a Huffman encoding, which is an encoding without shared prefixes. So, if A is `1000`, then there is no code `100` nor `10001`.

You can therefore organize the symbols in a binary tree. Use the compressed bits to walk from the root down to the leaf nodes, going left for 0 or right for 1. When you get to a leaf node, emit the character stored there, and start at the the root again.

Comment: I actually know about that, but due to some constraints that I did not mention, it is not possible here. It is a nice solution though

Comment: If you've got constraints that disallow reasonable solutions, tell us !! That said, if you understand the math behind Huffman encoding (or coding theory in general), apply it to your real problem domain.